# ILNumerics -- Major grid lines visibility from back face

Tags: plot, visibility, ilnumerics, gridlines

I would like to show (major) grid lines from all six faces of the plot cube regardless of the camera position.

By default the lines are only visible when viewing the front side of the plot cube face (not visible when looking through the back side of the face).

Basically, I would like to the grid lines to always be visible (just like the plot cube itself).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Currently not possible. Front side grid lines are always hidden. There is the chance of having it added in a future release. Add a feature request to the bugtracker: http://ilnumerics.net/mantis